# Kubectl behind corporative proxy

Tags: kubernetes, proxy, kubectl

These days I've been working with kubernetes and kubectl at work, the point is that each time I open a console I have to write:

```
export http_proxy=http://<username>:<pass>@<proxy>:8080  for unix OS
set http_proxy=http://<username>:<pass>@<proxy>:8080 for windows OS
```

because my Pc is behind a coorporative proxy.
This is very anoying because i have to write it a lot of time every days.

Is there any way to configure kubectl proxy with a config file or something else?

Comment: You need to set this proxy on the cluster configuration or only in your client terminal? is the cluster behind this proxy too or is it external?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to add the export line to your .bashrc (or equivalent if you're using another shell) as this is sourced every time you open up a new terminal.

Comment: Yes but sometimes I work at home and I dont need to set the proxy. So I will have to add and delete such line in my bashrc. At list is much better than every time i open a console wirte the command! thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem some months ago.

What I did to fix this was to start to use iTerm2 (I'm using Mac) and set PROFILES.

You can have 1 profile to work from office and another to work from home, then you can set some commands when you enter the profile: you can set proxies, ssh login.. whatever =)

Hope it helps.